# Nullsets and paving of nullsets

Tags: measure-theory

I am considering the measure space $(\mathcal{X},\mathbb{E},\mu)$ and the paving of $\mu$-nullsets gives as:

$\mathbb{N}_{\mu}= \left\{ N \subseteq \mathcal{X} : \exists E \in \ \mathbb{E}, \mu(E)=0  \right\}$

I am asked to show the following:

a) If $M \subseteq N$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}_{\mu}$ then $M \in \mathbb{N}_{\mu}$

b) If $\mu(E)=0$ then $E \in \mathbb{N}_{\mu}$

**My attempt:**

a)

If $M \in \mathbb{N}_{\mu}$ then it must hold that $\exists E \in \ \mathbb{E}$ such that $M \subseteq E$ and $ \mu(E)=0$.

Choose $E=N$ (we can do this since $N \in \mathbb{N}_{\mu}$). Then $M \subseteq N$ which is satisfied by assumption.

By assumption we have that $N \in \mathbb{N}_{\mu}$ which means that $\exists E \in \ \mathbb{E}$ such that $N \subseteq E$ and $ \mu(E)=0$. Since $\mu(E)=0$ then $E$ is countable. Since $N \subseteq E$ then $N$ is also countable and therefore $\mu(N)=0$.

Since $M \subseteq E$ and $\mu(E)=0$ for $E=N$ then $M \in \mathbb{N}_{\mu}$.

b)

Assume that $\mu(E)=0$. Notice that $E \subseteq E$ is always true. Hence there existst an $E \in \mathbb{E}$ (namely $E$ itself) such that $E \subseteq E$ and $\mu(E)=0$. Therefore $E \in \mathbb{N}_{\mu}$.

The above may seem trivial but I would like some feedback on my reasoning. Is it acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the  condition $N \subseteq E$ in the definition of $\mathbb N_{\mu}$.

It is not true that sets of measure $0$ are countable, so your proof is not valid.

If $M \subseteq N$ and $N \in \mathbb N_{\mu}$ then there exists $E \in \mathbb E$ such that $ N \subseteq E$ and $\mu (E)=0$. The same $E$ works for $M$ also, so $N \in N_{\mu}$.

For b) your proof is correct.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I missed the condition. I see the mistake with regards to countability. The same $E$ works because $M \subseteq N$? Is this sufficient as a reason?

Comment: @saleem Yes, that is sufficient.